# R Shiny invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: shiny

I got an error  "invalid subscript type 'list' " while uploading file1

```
audi
chevrolet
dodge
ford
hyundai
```

I need to print all row based on file1. My shiny code as follows

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
            multiple = TRUE,
            accept = c("text/csv",
                       "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                       ".csv"))),
  mainPanel(
  tableOutput("contents"))))
  server <- function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({
  req(input$file1)
  data <- as.matrix(mpg)
  df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
 data[df,]})}
 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The object `df` you are making is a data frame.  You're then trying to subset a matrix with a data frame, which won't work.  For this to work, `df` would have to be either a vector of row-names or a vector of row-numbers you wanted to extract.

Comment: I used df<-readLines(df) and got error as like ths "'con' is not a connection"

Comment: Can you post the contents `mpg`?

Comment: mpg from ggplot2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not reproducible.

- Need to tell people where the `mpg` is coming from: `ggplot2::mpg`. If I am not an experienced R user, I don't know what you are talking about.
- Say clearly "my file1 looks like this, see below:", rather than just post a random code chunk. You did a good example with the second chunk:

> I need to print all row based on file1. My shiny code as follows

I have to guess that you have a file that only contains the manufacturer names and you want to use it to filter the `mpg` data.

You need to do this:

```r
library(shiny)
# ignore this if you have your file
write.csv(
    data.frame(
        manufacturer = c("audi", "chevrolet", "dodge", "ford", "hyundai")
    ), 
    "mydf.csv",
    quote = FALSE,
    row.names = FALSE)
# starts from here
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      accept = c("text/csv",
                                 "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                 ".csv")
            )
        ),
        mainPanel(
            tableOutput("contents")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$contents <- renderTable({
        req(input$file1)
        data <- as.matrix(ggplot2::mpg)
        df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
        manufacturer <- unique(df[, 1])
        data[data[, 1] %in% manufacturer, ]
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I created a csv file `mydf.csv` that only has the names you provided.

- Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before posting your code in the future.
- A minor issue: try to [indent](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html) your code better so other people can have a better reading experience.